# Orbeon form builder limitation

Tags: orbeon

We faced several limitations when creating form using form builder:

1. When I drag an UI control into a grid cell, the UI control's label and the UI control itself are top down aligned. How to make both aligned at the same row (side by side). I could only figure out the way to do this by using bootstrap CSS.
2. When we started to customize the form with CSS more & more due to the form builder limitation, the form designer no longer show the exact form output. This trouble us as we need to test/publish the form to view actual output which defeat the purpose of WYSIWYG editor.
3. for the time component, is there any option to prefix zero in front of selected hour?

Appreciate anyone can help on this.

Note: 
I am using orbeon forms 2016.2 for the form development.

Comment: For reference I already [replied in the forum](http://discuss.orbeon.com/Orbeon-form-builder-limitation-td4661765.html).